# Awk: Parse xml to csv with empty tag

Tags: xml, csv, awk

I have a script to parse a xml into csv. I don't need to take tags where value is empty for exemple i have this

```
<root>
  <record>
   <country>US</country>  
  <data>
            <id_client>50C</id_client>  
               <mail></mail>
            <adress>10 </adress>
            <num_tel>001</num_tel>
            <name>toto</name>
            <birth>01/30/008</birth>        
  </data> 
  <data>
            <id_client>100K</id_client>  
            <adress>10  </adress>
               <mail></mail>
              <num_tel></num_tel>
            <name>toto2</name>
            <birth>01/30/011</birth>                    
  </data> 
 </ record>
 <record>
   <country>China</country>  
  <data>
            <id_client>99E</id_client>  
            <mail>3@mail.com</mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <name>toto3</name>
            <birth>01/30/0008</birth>       
  </data> 
  <data>
            <id_client>77B</id_client>  
            <mail></mail>
            <adress>10  </adress>
            <num_tel>004</num_tel>
            <name>toto4</name>
            <birth>2001/05/01</birth>                   
  </data> 
  </record
  </root>
```

the result after parse with awk script

```
 country;id_client;name; num_tel;mail
 US;50C;toto1;001
 US;100K;toto2
 China;99E;toto3;;3@mail.com
 China;77B;toto4;004
```

Here is  the script  to generate my csv but i don't know how to deal with empty value in some tags like   num_tel and mail

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[><]"; OFS=";"
    n = split("country  id_client name num_tel mail birth ",tags,/ /)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {

        {printf "%s%s", tags[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS)}
    }
 }
{ tag2val[$2] = $3 }
 {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {

     if ($(f[n[4]]=="") {printf ""} 
     else if  ($(f[n[5]]=="") {printf ""} 
     else 
        printf "%s%s", tag2val[tags[i]], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't parsing *XML* - you work with plain text. I suggest to use a programming language which is able to parse and process XML, like python, ruby, php, perl ....

Comment: i don't have the possibility to use anything on the server in order to parse it that way i proceed this ways

Comment: Then ask for that. You see it is required.

Comment: sorry i corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't output what you say you want, instead it outputs what you should want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[<>]"
    OFS=";"
    n=split("country id_client name num_tel mail birth",tags,/ /)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", tags[i], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
NF==5 { tag2val[$2] = $3 }
/<\/data>/ {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", tag2val[tags[i]], (i<n?OFS:ORS)
    }
}
/<\/record>/ { delete tag2val }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
country;id_client;name;num_tel;mail;birth
US;50C;toto;001;;01/30/008
US;100K;toto2;;;01/30/011
China;99E;toto3;;3@mail.com;01/30/0008
China;77B;toto4;004;;2001/05/01
```

Comment: thank you again ! you save me a lot of time here ! Please can you explain me  { tag2val[$2] = $3 }

Comment: yes i know it, in fact it was you how show me this way first time but i did not got this part this is way this time i don't want to make the same mistake to not ask you why

Comment: OK, then add some prints to help debug and then tell me what YOU think it's doing and I'll tell you if you got it right and/or correct any misunderstanding.

Comment: the command output all the data by group of record link for every customer is it correctly said ? anyway i understand and the second loop FOR use the split for the data is it correct?

Comment: It's not outputing anything at that point it's just creating a mapping of the HTML tag (e.g. `name`) to it's value (e.g. `toto`). The FS setting is splitting $0 at every `>` or `<`, hence $2 is the tag and $3 the value. The for loop is just printing the values stored in the array.